# Process Exits with Error Code 100 on invoking AWS Lambda Container Image

Tags: google-chrome, aws-lambda, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html and created an image from an AWS base image for Lambda and tested it locally first before pushing it to ECR. On invoking function locally, I get expected results i.e. Error Code 0. But after pushing image on ECR and invoking it from AWS lambda console, I get following issue.

```
START RequestId: 55930a26-5d88-4d1f-9a5b-14599b369585 Version: $LATEST
[04:46:19] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[04:46:19] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[04:46:22] E/runner - Unable to start a WebDriver session.
[04:46:22] E/launcher - Error: NoSuchSessionError: invalid session id
at Object.throwDecodedError (/var/task/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:514:15)
at parseHttpResponse (/var/task/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:519:13)
at /var/task/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async Promise.all (index 0)
[04:46:22] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
2021-08-11T04:46:22.089Z    55930a26-5d88-4d1f-9a5b-14599b369585    INFO    error code:  100
END RequestId: 55930a26-5d88-4d1f-9a5b-14599b369585
REPORT RequestId: 55930a26-5d88-4d1f-9a5b-14599b369585  Duration: 9465.93 ms    Billed Duration: 10270 ms   Memory Size: 10000 MB   Max Memory Used: 314 MB Init Duration: 803.88 ms
```

My conf.js

```
exports.config = {
     directConnect: true,
    ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true,
    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
    'specs': ['index.js'],
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 1000 * 6,
        realtimeFailure: true,
        showColors: true,
        isVerbose: true,
        includeStackTrace: true,
        displaySpecDuration: true,
        print: function () {},
    },
    'capabilities': {
      'browserName': 'chrome',
        acceptInsecureCerts: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true,
        chromeOptions: {
            binary: "/usr/bin/google-chrome",
            "excludeSwitches": [ "enable-automation" ],
            "useAutomationExtension": false,
            args: ["--no-sandbox","--disable-web-security","--headless","--disable-dev-shm-usage","--disable-extensions", "--disable-gpu", "--start-maximized", "--disable-infobars"]
        }

    },
    framework: "jasmine"
};
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "protractor",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node_modules/.bin/protractor conf.js",
    "runlocal": "node_modules/.bin/sls invoke local --function protractor",
    "deploy": "node_modules/.bin/sls deploy"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "jasmine": "^3.8.0",
    "npm": "^6.14.14",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "protractor-beautiful-reporter": "^1.3.6"
  }
}
```

My dockerfile

```
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-nodejs:12
COPY index.js conf.js handler.js package*.json screenshots ./
ADD install-google-chrome.sh .
RUN chmod +x install-google-chrome.sh
RUN curl https://intoli.com/install-google-chrome.sh | bash
ADD gtk-firefox.sh .
RUN chmod 755 gtk-firefox.sh
RUN ./gtk-firefox.sh
RUN npm install
RUN node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager clean
RUN node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
CMD [ "handler.runtest" ]
```

handler.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports.runtest = (event, context, callback) => {

  var npm = require('npm');
  var path = require('path');
  var childProcess = require('child_process');
  var args = ['conf.js'];

  npm.load(function() {
    var child = childProcess
    .fork(path.join(npm.root, 'protractor/bin/protractor'), args)   
        .on('close', function(errorCode) {
      console.log('error code: ', errorCode);

      // Use this block to have Lambda respond when the tests are done.
      const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          message: `Selenium Test executed on Chrome ! Child process Error Code: ${errorCode}`,
        }),
      };
      callback(null, response);
    });
    process.on('SIGINT', child.kill);
  });


};
```

index.js

```
const {by} = require("protractor");
const {protractor} = require("protractor");
const {browser} = require("protractor");
describe('Google\'s Search Functionality', function() {
    it('can find search results', async function() {
        const signin = "Sign in"
        await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        await browser.get('https://google.com/ncr');
        await browser.findElement(by.name('q')).sendKeys('BrowserStack', protractor.Key.ENTER);
        const texti = browser.findElement(by.xpath('//a[contains(@href,"sign_in")]'));
        expect(await texti.getText()).toEqual(signin);
    });
});
```

Al these files are at same level in root project directory.

I googled a lot but not able to find proper resolution. Is it some permission issue?
As I don't understand what makes the same lambda container image fail in lambda console and not in local.

Comment: With 'invoking locally', do you mean executing the container image locally, or executing the code locally on your computer?

Comment: I mean to say executing the container image locally i.e.  locally test my Lambda function packaged as a container image using AWS Lambda Runtime Interface Emulator (RIE). I hit:
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{}'
and gets:
{"statusCode":200,"body":"{\"message\":\"Protractor Test executed on Chrome ! Child process Error Code: 0\"}"}%

Comment: I have even added chrome binary in conf.js, snippet-
```
    'capabilities': {
      'browserName': 'chrome',
        acceptInsecureCerts: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true,
        chromeOptions: {
            binary: "/usr/bin/google-chrome",
            "excludeSwitches": [ "enable-automation" ],
            "useAutomationExtension": false,
            args: ["--no-sandbox","--disable-web-security","--headless","--disable-dev-shm-usage","--disable-extensions", "--disable-gpu", "--start-maximized", "--disable-infobars"]
        }
```
  Still no luck.
Can you please help here?